# ndb transactions support for updating/rolling back multiple ndb model entries in the same transaction

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have webapp2 service in which inserts entries in mutiple NDB models which are not interdependent. 
Now what we require is that service should be in transaction. That is something fails in service then it should revert the complete transaction 
(eg. if an entry in inserted in first & second model and after that transaction fails then it should delete the record inserted in first model.)

I looked into ndb transactions but looks its not useful as it works for only one model at a time. Also I looked into cross group transactions but that is not required for my data structure.

For example

**Model Structure**

```
class ModelTestA(ndb.Model):
    field1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    field2 = ndb.StringProperty()

class ModelTestB(ndb.Model):
    field1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    field2 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**WebApp2 Service**

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb        
from google.appengine.api import datastore_errors
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def put_entity():
    try:
        testa_obj = ModelTestA()
        testa_obj.field1 = "ModelAF1"
        testa_obj.field2 = "ModelAF2"
        dbsput(testa_obj)
        0/1 # also tried this raise datastore_errors.TransactionFailedError('The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.')
        testb_obj = ModelTestB()
        testb_obj.field1 = "ModelBF1"
        testb_obj.field2 = "ModelBF2"
        dbsput(testb_obj)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)

class TransactionTesting(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        put_entity()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: how did you conclude that the transactions are limited to just one model?

Comment: Based on documentation it will be single for model. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions

Comment: There is nothing in that document that says you are limited to a single model.  The examples only use a single model so they are clear.

Comment: All entities need to be in a single entity group if you are not using XG transactions.

Comment: From your code, instead of throwing Divide by zero exception, just raise ndb's Rollback() exception ! That should work.

Comment: Can you try removing try, except and then test it again ?
Reason being you have handled the exception and the transaction is complete. So it wont remove those entries.

Comment: @Kartik Yes if i remove try, except it will be working.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are model (kind) agnostic, so are not limited to a single model.

Transactions only care about entity groups.

- If all entities are in a single entity group, you are limited by "Maximum size for a transaction" (currently 10 MiB).
- If entities are in multiple entity groups, there is an additional limit of "Maximum number of entity groups that can be accessed in a transaction" (currently 25)

The transactional notation in NDB requires you to let the except be raised out of the function for it to rollback the transaction. In your code the `try ... except` clauses are swallowing the exception, which leads NDB to think the transaction completed normally.